# Check value match in array of objects

Tags: javascript, authentication

I am trying to make a really simple test login function, with email and password. I've created 2 objects and put them in an array.

```
let adminLoginObject = {
    email : "admin",
    password : "1234"
};
let userLoginObject = {
    email : "user",
    password : "1234"
};

let loginArray = new Array(
    adminLoginObject, 
    userLoginObject
);
```

And then I'm trying to see if the inputs from the form match an object's values.

i have tried the following:

```
var emailResult = loginArray.filter(obj => {
    return obj.email === email;
});
var emailR = loginArray.some(x=> x.password === password && x.email == email);
```

But it seems no matter what, it always returns false or undefined.

I get the values of my inputs with this.

```
const loginForm = document.getElementById('login-form');

const inputs = loginForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
    const password = inputs[1].value;
    const email = inputs[0].value;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `return obj.email === email;` is trying to match each Object's `email` property against a variable named `email`. Are you caching `email` as a variable somewhere?

Comment: @ItoPizarro yep, the last bit of code in my post (const email)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure if that was a different example. My bad.

Comment: @ItoPizarro nvm.. im about to yell at my screen, i switched the email and password... so when i was trying to get the email, i got the password, and reversed... so.. now it works.. hah... its so late...

Comment: @dandavis that was just a misprint.

Answer (score 0):

in my HTML form, the email was first, and then the password. 
And in my javascript, I got the password first and then the email. 
Therefore I would never get a correct on my filter. 
So switching them, made it all work.